# Use BLE L2CAP CoC on Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-kernel, l2cap

I am trying to use Windows PC as a Central and connect it to BLE L2CAP CoC opened by Android smartphone using [BluetoothAdapter#listenUsingL2capChannel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#listenUsingL2capChannel()). From what I found after looking through [MSDN documentation dedicated to the use of Bluetooth on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/), I assumed I had to implement kernel-mode driver similar to [Bluetooth Echo L2CAP Client Profile Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/bluetooth-echo-l2cap-profile-driver/). But it looks like [BRBs for opening l2cap channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/bthddi/ns-bthddi-_brb_l2ca_open_enhanced_channel) are not designed to support LE Credit Based Flow Control Mode (which I assume is the mode the channel opened by Android is configured in). And that leads to the conclusion that one can not use the transmission directly over BLE L2CAP channel on Windows.

What I expect in the answer is a confirmation or a contradiction to my conclusion and sharing the experience of setting up an interaction between Android and Windows using BLE. Is using the GATT the only option for this?